# Extract directory names

Tags: java

I want to extract only the last level directory names. Where did I do wrong? My directories only have 1 path in it, does it matter?

```
ArrayList<String> directoryNames = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < directories.size(); i++){

    int index = directories.get(i).lastIndexOf("/");
    String string = directories.get(i).substring(index);
    directoryNames.add(string);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to extract only the last level directory names. Where did I do wrong? My directories only have 1 path in it, does it matter?

No, the total String in your `directories` doesn't matter. The problem is the following code:

```
int index = directories.get(i).lastIndexOf("/");
String string = directories.get(i).substring(index);
```

where you don't catch the probability that the directory is not a valid path. `String.lastIndexOf` will return -1 if no occurrence is found (from [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(int))):

> In either case, if no such character occurs in this string, then -1 is returned.

So, check for the occurrence by updating your code to something like this:

```
List<String> directoryNames = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < directories.size(); i++){

   // Instead of using "/", use File.separatorChar because separator char
   // is dependent with the system. 
   int index = directories.get(i).lastIndexOf(File.separatorChar);

   // check only for valid directory name.
   if(index >= 0) {
      // don't include the "/" as the name
      String lastLevel = directories.get(i).substring(index + 1);
      directoryNames.add(lastLevel);
   }

}
```